# Using Django's built in change password feature: [Errno 65] No route to host

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to implement Django's built in change password feature. I am getting the following error after clicking reset on the initial /user/password/reset page:

[Errno 65] No route to host at location socket.py in create_connection

I am using the standard urls:

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', 
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'},
    name="password_reset"),
(r'^user/password/reset/done/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
(r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', 
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
(r'^user/password/done/$', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

Email settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'my.email.host'
EMAIL_PORT = 'myport'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MYPW'
```

custom reset template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Reset Password{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Please specify your email address to receive instructions for resetting it.</p>

<form action="" method="post">
<div style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
</div>
 {{ form.email.errors }}
<p><label for="id_email">E-mail address:</label> {{ form.email }} <input type="submit" value="Reset password" /></p>
```

{% endblock %}

custom email template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% autoescape off %}

You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm" uidb36=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Check your email server specified in `EMAIL_HOST` setting is accessible.

Comment: I am using the settings specified under "SMTP account" here- http://wiki.gandi.net/en/mail/standard-settings